# How do I format varying height columns?

Tags: css, multiple-columns, bootstrap-4, row-height

I'm starting to get really lost in the whole Bootstrap/flexbox grid system. I'm trying to achieve a dynamic, 2 column layout with one large `col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-8` and two small columns of: `col-sm-12.col-md-6.col-lg-4`

This is what I want for large screens:
[image: This]

and this for medium-sized screens:
[image: this]

But, this is what I get!:
[image: this]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1">
          <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="big" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
      <p> Lots of text </p>
    </div>
    <div id="small1" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <p> Little text </p>
    </div>
    <div id="small2" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <p> Little text </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Right now, your provided HTML plus the standard Bootstrap CSS file provides the exact behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an ideal opportunity for a nested grid:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 
  <div id="big" class="col-12 col-lg-8">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui quos corporis quisquam officiis sint explicabo, pariatur eveniet, quibusdam exercitationem enim quia, repudiandae laudantium reiciendis dolore quaerat asperiores accusamus! Similique dolorem ipsa veniam ducimus, excepturi nisi odio! Est quibusdam tenetur laudantium blanditiis. Corrupti omnis veniam, fugit fugiat explicabo deleniti, dolorem recusandae quod fuga qui consectetur, possimus? Dignissimos maiores, at possimus officia minus, voluptatum, ipsa magnam iste voluptatem animi quam tempore! Laborum omnis, ad soluta ducimus eligendi, fugiat natus voluptatibus sint possimus! Nihil qui excepturi, necessitatibus ipsam accusantium delectus cum culpa iure.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
   <div class="row">
   
    <div id="small1" class="col-6 col-lg-12">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit ipsa voluptas ut, id sunt provident recusandae maxime a culpa, dolore iusto explicabo, nesciunt nobis necessitatibus laudantium temporibus! Corporis aperiam, deleniti.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="small2" class="col-6 col-lg-12">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit ipsa voluptas ut, id sunt provident recusandae maxime a culpa, dolore iusto explicabo, nesciunt nobis necessitatibus laudantium temporibus! Corporis aperiam, deleniti.</p>
    </div>
   
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</div>
```

In the above example your primary grid has two columns; the first is 12-columns wide at all breakpoints below `lg`.  At `lg` it is 8-columns wide.  The second column follows the same pattern but at `lg` it is 4-columns wide.

Inside the second column we have the nested grid.  This has a different breakpoint for each column: 6-columns wide for breakpoints below `lg` and at `lg` each column is 12-columns wide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="big" class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      <p><b>1</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui quos corporis quisquam officiis sint explicabo, pariatur eveniet, quibusdam exercitationem enim quia, repudiandae laudantium reiciendis dolore quaerat asperiores accusamus! Similique dolorem ipsa veniam ducimus, excepturi nisi odio! Est quibusdam tenetur laudantium blanditiis. Corrupti omnis veniam, fugit fugiat explicabo deleniti, dolorem recusandae quod fuga qui consectetur, possimus? Dignissimos maiores, at possimus officia minus, voluptatum, ipsa magnam iste voluptatem animi quam tempore! Laborum omnis, ad soluta ducimus eligendi, fugiat natus voluptatibus sint possimus! Nihil qui excepturi, necessitatibus ipsam accusantium delectus cum culpa iure.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="small1" class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
          <p><b>2</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit ipsa voluptas ut, id sunt provident recusandae maxime a culpa, dolore iusto explicabo, nesciunt nobis necessitatibus laudantium temporibus! Corporis aperiam, deleniti.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="small2" class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
          <p><b>3</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit ipsa voluptas ut, id sunt provident recusandae maxime a culpa, dolore iusto explicabo, nesciunt nobis necessitatibus laudantium temporibus! Corporis aperiam, deleniti.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What is happening for different devices?**

- *small view (like iPhone 6):*
  All columns have the same full width (`col-12`) of the device. I don't recommend to create two columns for column number 2 and 3.
- *medium view (like iPad):*
  The first column is full width (`col-12`) and above the columns 2 and 3. The columns 2 and 3 are in one row with same width (`col-6`), next to each other.
- *large view (like Desktop / Laptop):*
  The column 1 is using 2/3 of the width. The columns 2 and 3 are on the right column (1/3 of width), about each other.

To check the different breakpoints I recommend the browser plugin (Google Chrome) [*Window Resizer*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) or the device toolbar on Google Chrome (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> on developer tools <kbd>F12</kbd>).

Comment: Should you be combining `.row` with `.col-*-*` like that?

Comment: it's working so if you want so save some traffic you can do it. I fixed the code and split the column and row.